TOTP automation is not working using selenium chrome webdriver for fyres api
I am trying to automate the totp login for fyres APi using Selenium and I am able to enter the user ID and failing at the  totp.
Below is the sample code use.
code:
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)

time.sleep(1)
login_with_clien_id_x_path='//*[@id="login_client_id"]'
elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, login_with_clien_id_x_path)
elem.click()
time.sleep(1)
client_id_input_x_path='//*[@id="fy_client_id"]'
elem2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, client_id_input_x_path)
elem2.send_keys("YU02138")
elem2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(1)
#
t=tp.TOTP(totp_key).now()

Failing from here, as fyres has added human detection and Selenium is not able to handle human verification.
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="first"]').send_keys(t[0])
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="second"]').send_keys(t[1])
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="third"]').send_keys(t[2])
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="fourth"]').send_keys(t[3])
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="fifth"]').send_keys(t[4])
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sixth"]').send_keys(t[5])

# click on the button to complete 2FA

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="confirmOtpSubmit"]').click()
time.sleep(1)

